# Can I use a checkbox to do the equivalent of commenting/uncommenting a single line of code?

Tags: java, android, xml, checkbox, android-checkbox

I have 1 line of code in an XML file that is read by another app when installed on the same device. Can I give the user the option to not use this line of code by giving them a checkbox? The goal is to essentially "comment out" this line when the checkbox is pressed.

One thought I had was to tell the computer to ignore the specific line of code when the checkbox is selected. However, it needs to do more than this and delete/inactivate the line altogether so that the other app does not read it. Is there a simpler way to do this?

**Here is the code in question, line 4 with the iconmask (res/xml/this_file):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>

    <iconmask img1="iconmask" />

    ...


</resources>
```

Comment: Is the code that you want to remove in the XML file or the Java file?

Comment: I want to remove the code in the XML file. @AkashBhave

Comment: Are you using Shared Preferences in your android app? if so you can put default value for your key, and add a checkbox to indicate if you are going to use this default value or not. Shared Preferences are XML files, and you can give the user the ability to check/uncheck the option from the preference screen

Comment: Can you give us the exact line of code so that we can see what you are trying to remove?

Comment: Added the XML code in the original post. @AkashBhave

Comment: I am not using SharedPreferences unfortunately. I do not believe the other app can read from a file other than the current one with its specific name + location. @F.sh

Comment: Why not set up a conditional statement to only read said line if a condition is true?

Comment: That could work! Though since it is another app that looks for this specific line of code, will the conditional statement still "blind it," so to speak? @BR89

Comment: What kind of "information/data" are you exchanging between the two apps?

Comment: The other app is not mine, so I am not certain, but I believe the data is simply in the form of Java from the other app (which makes it essentially a library in this regard) which tells my app to apply my own image over the top of two different images in my app. @F.sh

Comment: @F.sh Another comment helped me think of a good idea to try, so I'll work on that and report back. Thank you for your help thus far!